# StyleConverterImpl class not found after trying executing generated jar file

Tags: java, deployment, jar, classnotfoundexception, executable-jar

Hey guys so I have a generated jar file:

[image: jar file]

And the project uses two external jar files (fillo and jphoenix):

[image: external jar files]

After I tried double click on the jar file nothing happens (it just shows the loading circle and thats it), I decided to run the jar file using cmd:

```
PS C:\Users\maljursa\Desktop\JavaFXApplication2\dist> java -jar "BFFT_One4All.jar"
```

And the error I got is:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/StyleConverterImpl
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXButton.java:208)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton.<init>(JFXButton.java:156)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at Main.Main.start(Main.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
Exception running application Main.Main
```

Appearently the class `com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl` can't be found, but as far I can remember I don't remember using this import.

Comment: *And the project uses two external jar files (fillo and jphoenix)* what if they are using said class?

Comment: @Lino well if they were using the class and I deploy the project shouldn't the external libs be also deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Java 10: Try downgrading it to Java 8 or 9 as currently JPhoenix is not available for Java 10.